# How to render and image after a collision LibGdx

Tags: libgdx

I want to Know why in the render method, when I remove the image that have make the collision it not draw another one

```
public class Level003 extends Level 
{
    /**
     * The TextureAtlas with the interface elements
     */


    protected SpriteBatch batch;

    protected TextureAtlas interfaceAtlas = Assets.manager.get(Constants.INTERFACE_ATLAS_PATH, TextureAtlas.class);

    protected DoubleButtonOrange teal;

    protected ArrayList<DoubleButtonOrange> relation; 

    protected RigthRectangle white;

    protected WrongRectangle orange;

    protected Vector2 coordinates;

    protected PauseButton pause;

    protected TimerLevel time;

    protected NextButton next;


    public Level003(WorldController wc)
    {
        super(wc, "Relation", "Find the relation", "Yasmin Rodriguez", Constants.GRAY);
    }

    @Override
    protected void init()
    {   
        Vector2 coordinatesPause = new Vector2(323,0);
        Vector2 coordinatesNext = new Vector2(0,0);
        GameInterface gi = new GameInterface(this, 0, Constants.INTERFACE_Y);
        pause = new PauseButton(coordinatesPause, 157, 76, gi);
        next = new NextButton(coordinatesNext, 157, 76);
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        Vector2 coordinates = new Vector2(240,400);
        white = new RigthRectangle(coordinates);
        orange = new WrongRectangle(coordinates);
        teal = new DoubleButtonOrange(coordinates,"ciao");
        relation = new ArrayList<DoubleButtonOrange>();
        time = new TimerLevel();
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            relation.add(teal);

    }

    @Override
    public void render( final SpriteBatch batch)
    {   
        for(int i=0;i<relation.size;i++)
        { 
            relation.get(i).draw(bacth);
           if(relation.get(i).collision() == true)
           { relation.get(i).removeImage();
              relation.get(i+1).draw(batch);
           }
         }

        batch.begin();
        time.drawTime(batch);
        white.draw(batch);
        orange.draw(batch);
        pause.draw(batch);
        next.draw(batch);
        batch.end();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are keeping in **relation** Array 5 of the same reference to **DoubleButtonOrange** object - when you are disposing one of this 5 "instances" what you think you do, you actually disposing all of them (cause they are all the same).

In your **init** method just create 5 anothers instances of **DoubleButtonOrange**. Instead of

```
    teal = new DoubleButtonOrange(coordinates,"ciao");
    relation = new ArrayList<DoubleButtonOrange>();
    time = new TimerLevel();
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        relation.add(teal);
```

make

```
    //nothing here
    relation = new ArrayList<DoubleButtonOrange>();
    time = new TimerLevel();
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        DoubleButtonOrange teal = new DoubleButtonOrange(coordinates,"ciao");
        relation.add(teal);
```

or even `relation.add( new DoubleButtonOrange(coordinates,"ciao") );`